# Forward requests on Public IP to Private IP Azure

Tags: azure

I have a Ubuntu VM running on Azure with Private IP 10.0.0.4 and I have assigned a Public IP x.x.x.x. An application is listening on several ports on the private IP address and I cannot connect to them from external network.

How do I forward any request on any port on Public IP to 10.0.0.4 on the same port.

Comment: Check your NSG (firewall) of the Azure VM and also if the Ubuntu VM has Firewall enabled.

Answer (score 1):

You remove the public IP from the server and put it on a public load balancer. Then you point the traffic from the load balancer back to the private IP of your vm.

> A public Load Balancer maps the public IP address and port of incoming traffic to the private IP address and port of the VM

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/concepts-limitations#public-load-balancer